# Copy Activity from a MySQL view with parameters to Azure SQL database with Azure Data Factory

Tags: mysql, azure, variables, parameters, azure-data-factory

I try to copy a MySQL view with parameters to Azure SQL database with Azure Data Factory. Here is the query for the Copy Activity:

```
SET @dDebut=20220201;
SET @dFin=20220228; 

select vue_movements_of_month_with_param.* from (select @dDebut, @dFin) param , vue_movements_of_month_with_param
LIMIT 10;
```

That's what I run in HeidiSQL. The view contains functions that take above parameters. In ADF, I define the parameters dDebut and dFin as parameters pipeline:

[image]

Then I use the Copy Activity in ADF with the MySQL linked service:

[image]

by using the following query:

```
@concat('SELECT vue_movements_of_month_with_param.* FROM (SELECT ', pipeline().parameters.dDebut, ', ', pipeline().parameters.dFin, ') param, vue_movements_of_month_with_param LIMIT 10')
```

But the results returns an empty table. It seems that my parameters are not recognized. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Hi, Can you try including your first query (with SET @dDebut) and add a pipeline parameter instead of a variable value 20220201?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering me. I tried:@concat('SET @dDebut=', pipeline().parameters.dDebut,'; SET @dFin=', pipeline().parameters.dFin, '; SELECT vue_movements_of_month_with_param.* FROM (SELECT @dDebut, @dFin) param, vue_movements_of_month_with_param LIMIT 10'); However, I have a syntax error but I can't see where. It seems that ADF doesn't like @. BTW, the view  vue_movements_of_month_with_param are built based on 2 functions: GetDateDebut (= BEGIN RETURN @dDebut; END ) and GetDateFin (= BEGIN RETURN @dFIN; END) and so these latters takes user defined variables. Is that a problem for ADF?

Comment: For debugging, can you add this expression in set variable activity and see what results its giving?

Comment: I tried with set variable activity and the query becomes: @concat('SET dDebut=', variables('dDebut'),'; SET dFin=', variables('dFin'), '; SELECT vue_movements_of_month_with_param.* FROM (SELECT dDebut, dFin) param, vue_movements_of_month_with_param LIMIT 10'). I get an error code 9602: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][MySQL] Unknown system variable 'dDebut'. Does it mean the view doesn't take user defined variables from MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Instead of creating a view with parameters that are stored as *user-defined variables*, I use a stored procedure that takes the required parameters for inputs.